# Adding SQLite.db file from the assets and show in List view

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Hello experts I am trying using existing database in my flutter application  please help after importing database in my app how to show in my list view  from existing database my table is hebrew  and column name is id,eng,urdu,hebrew

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;


class DictionaryDataBaseHelper {
  Database _db;

  Future<void> init() async {
    io.Directory applicationDirectory =
    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    String dbPathEnglish =
    path.join(applicationDirectory.path, "hebrewapp.db");

    bool dbExistsEnglish = await io.File(dbPathEnglish).exists();

    if (!dbExistsEnglish) {
      // Copy from asset
      ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path.join("assets", "hebrewapp.db"));
      List<int> bytes =
      data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

      // Write and flush the bytes written
      await io.File(dbPathEnglish).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    }

    this._db = await openDatabase(dbPathEnglish);
  }
}
```

//here I want show data in my list view here listvew app source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Dictionary extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DictionaryState createState() => _DictionaryState();
}

class _DictionaryState extends State<Dictionary> {





  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: Text('Hebrew Dictionary'),
      ),

      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text('hebrew',style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20
                    ),),
                    subtitle: Text('העברעיש',style: TextStyle(

                    ),),
                  ),




                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ) ,

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How to you retrieving a data from database?

Comment: @fartem yes but from existing database

Comment: Are you have entities that mapping to data in database? For example, if database contains table `users`, in app exists it representation in class? Class `User` or something?

Comment: in simple this database create through sqlite db browser manager  now I want show in my app please tell me how used it inside my app I explore lot of tutorial but no one used existing database that's why I posted here

Comment: What functionality do you implementing?

Comment: @fartem just want database only

Comment: You can create a database internally and in app add functions for create default structure with needed tables.

Comment: thanks I found another solution I convert db into json fetch data in app successfully now I want make search filter